# Cookie expiration day is always set to 7 days

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a function to set a cookies. It sets an `Expires` value for the cookie using the function below.

If I change `30` to anything from `1` to `7` the `Expires` value works as expected. If I pass anything more than `7`, the `Expires` value is always 7 days from now. Why is that?

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    const expires = `expires=${d.toUTCString()}`;
    document.cookie = `${cname}=${cvalue};${expires};path=/;SameSite=Strict`; // Using the new SameSite attribute: https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/
    document.cookie = `${cname}=${cvalue};${expires};path=/;Secure`; // Fallback for legacy browsers: https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/
}
```

Comment: It may very well be your browser having that limit in place: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3443

Comment: Thanks, never realized this!

Comment: Just tried it in console and got the cookie added with expiration set to 30 days as expected from the code. No issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript itself does not have any limitation in place that would cause this.

But your browser may very well have. Either a regular browser setting or some installed add-on might limit for how long cookies are allowed to live, for 7 days or 30 or whatever limit the user feels comfortable with. See e.g. https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3443 .